# Effect is stuck in an infinite loop - Ngrx/effects

Tags: angular, observable, ngrx, ngrx-effects

When `new SaveModelAction()` is called, the corresponding Effect gets stuck in an infinite loop.

This the effect:

```
@Effect() saveModelAction = this.action$.pipe(
    ofType(SAVE_MODEL),
    switchMap((action: any) => {
      const storageMetaData: StorageData = action.payload;
      return this.modelService.loadState()
        .pipe(
          switchMap((state: State) => {
            const model: Model = AnalysisUtils.convertStateToModel(state, storageMetaData);
            return this.modelService.saveModel(model)
              .pipe(
                map(() => new SavingModelCompleteAction),
                catchError((error: Error) => this.createErrorObservableAndLog(error))
              );
          }),
          catchError((error: Error) => this.createErrorObservableAndLog(error))
        );
    })
  );
```

Additional info:

1. Within the relevant component, the `SaveModelAction` is only disptached once.
2. When subscribing to the state at `this.modelService.loadState()`, `take(1)` is used.
3. `this.modelService.saveModel(model)` does nothing except sending the model to the backend (and returning an observable.

Can anyone point me in the right direction on where my issue is? Thanks!

Comment: Firstly, concatening Observables is a really bad idea, it should look like that : https://pastebin.com/RdVBC4jH
Could you provide a stackblitz ? Take a look at this page : https://github.com/ngrx/store-devtools it will helps you a lot for debugging your store Actions.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why it is a bad idea? It seems like chaining observables like this is described in in the official docs: https://ngrx.io/guide/effects

Also, if I use your example, I'm not able to pass the local variables down the chain.

Really appreciate your input, so if I got that wrong I'll gladly stand corrected!

Devtools haven't helped in this case so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`switchMap` has a different purpose.

As I can see, you just want to flatten Observables, so you should use `flatMap` or `mergeMap` instead of `switchMap`.
More about these operators: https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/switchmap.html

Try something like this:

```
@Effect() saveModelAction = this.action$.pipe(
ofType(SAVE_MODEL),
mergeMap((action: any) => {
  const storageMetaData: StorageData = action.payload;
  return this.modelService.loadState()
    .pipe(
      mergeMap((state: State) => {
        const model: Model = AnalysisUtils.convertStateToModel(state, storageMetaData);
        return this.modelService.saveModel(model)
          .pipe(
            map(() => new SavingModelCompleteAction),
            catchError((error: Error) => this.createErrorObservableAndLog(error))
          );
      }),
      catchError((error: Error) => this.createErrorObservableAndLog(error))
    );
})
);
```

Also it's a common mistake that constants have the same primitive value. In your case please check that SAVE_MODEL_COMPLETE != SAVE_MODEL. If they have the same primitive value then you keep dispatching the same action.

Comment: Tried, the issue persists sadly. Thanks for the link though, I still don't quite get all the operators.

Comment: What is the `type` property of `SavingModelCompleteAction`?

Comment: It's a common mistake that constants have the same primitive value. In your case  please check that SAVE_MODEL_COMPLETE != SAVE_MODEL. If they have the same primitive value then you keep dispatching the same action.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was the issue! I messed up when defining the constants:

`export const SAVE_DFD = '[Storage] Saving Model';
export const SAVE_DFD_COMPLETE = '[Storage] Saving Model';` Can you edit your answer with the solutions? Then I can accept it.

Comment: Thanks again, you saved me a lot of headache!

Comment: I'm glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, effect was stuck in an infinite loop and take(1) solved it for dispatching it only once.

The problem was that I had 2 actions which had the same type :(

This should work perfectly, so in case of infinite loop of effect or action, check the constants type :)

Good luck everyone!

Comment: You saved me. I was breaking my head trying to figure this out. This issue started after upgrading to ngrx v11. It worked fine earlier, but this issue started cropping up after the upgrade. THANKS, A TON.